# How to enforce correct usage of "this" at compile time when passing functions?

Tags: typescript

When passing methods to other classes it can easily happen that the context of `this` is messed up. Lets consider the following simple example:

```
class Counter {
    public count: number
    private callMyCallback: CallMyCallback
    constructor() {
        this.count = 0

        // works 
        this.callMyCallback = new CallMyCallback(() => this.countFunctionCalls())
        // doesn't work (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count'))
        this.callMyCallback = new CallMyCallback(this.countFunctionCalls)
    }
    private countFunctionCalls() {
        console.log("Callback called")
        this.count = this.count + 1;
    }
}

class CallMyCallback {
    constructor(callback: ()=> void) {
        callback();
    }
}

const counter = new Counter()
console.log(counter.count)
```

My problem is that both ways of passing the callback function to `callMyCallback` are compiled without error or warning. Using `this` wrongly can only be detected when running the application. I didn't find any corresponding tsconfig setting, or anything else helpful. Is there any setting/library/... to enforce the correct usage of `this`?

Comment: This is essentially a missing feature of TypeScript, requested at [ms/TS#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968).  You can manually annotate `this` parameters everywhere to get the desired behavior, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w6z2rw), but it's not great because if you forget to do this then it won't help.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment. As you pointed out the workaround is not great, but I guess it is the best that we have at the moment. If you write this as an answer I will accept it of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeScript doesn't support strict enforcement of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context.  There is a longstanding open request for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) but it has not been implemented (it seems to be hard to do so and maintain adequate compiler performance).

You can annotate individual methods and functions with appropriate [`this` parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) to get the desired  checking on those methods and functions, but it doesn't happen automatically:

```
class CallMyCallback {
  constructor(callback: (this: void) => void) {
    // add ------------> ^^^^^^^^^^
    callback();
  }
}

class Counter {
  private countFunctionCalls(this: Counter) {
    // add ----------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log("Callback called")
    this.count = this.count + 1;
  }

  public count: number
  private callMyCallback: CallMyCallback

  constructor() {
    this.count = 0

    this.callMyCallback = new CallMyCallback(() => this.countFunctionCalls()) // okay
    this.callMyCallback = new CallMyCallback(this.countFunctionCalls) // error!
    // ------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //   The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
  }
}
```

This is currently the closest you can get, as far as I know.  Obviously it's not great, because the developer needs to remember to add these checks, and a developer who's aware that they need to do this would probably avoid passing around unbound methods in the first place.

So, if you want to see this changed, it couldn't hurt to go to microsoft/TypeScript#7968, give it a , and (because the issue is tagged as "Awaiting More Feedback") provide a comment on your use case, why it's compelling, and why the available workarounds don't suffice.  It probably wouldn't *help* much (there are a *lot* of outstanding feature requests and they can't all be implemented), but it couldn't hurt.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)